# Have JQuery-UI datepicker format initial date correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, datepicker

Hi I want to use the JQuery-UI datepicker as an AngularJS Directive.  I feel like I'm almost there but the JQuery-UI datepicker does not format initial data if it isn't already in the correct format.  I created a JSFiddle for people to play with and was wondering what the most elegant way to fix this problem might be?

http://jsfiddle.net/cnrWY/

and the code in a nutshell
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input id="myDateInput" type="text" ng-model="myDateTime" datepicker />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', function() { })
.directive('datepicker', function () { 
    return {        
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function () {
                $(element).datepicker({                    
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    onSelect: function(date) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    }
                });
            });
        }    
    }
}).controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myDateTime = new Date();
});
```

Note: I tried putting formatting in the directive but sometimes the date isn't there yet.  Like the directive fires before the value is in the input/scope.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that onSelect event is not triggered, until you explicitly select date. So model doesn't get updated. You should observe your model and keep it formatted by yourself.

Why don't you try to use [ui-date](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date) directive?